# How to correctly to pass the model for ComboBox from python (pyQt5) to QML?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qml

To display any list in QML (in ComboBox or ListView), I need to create a class that will be the model for that list. Then i need to pass this class to ContextProperty. But if i have, for example, 50 ComboBoxes, then i will have 50 classes that i have to pass to the ContextProperty. Is this the correct approach? Will this not affect memory consumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a model that manages the data so that the list is associated with a role as shown below:

```py
import os
import random
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtProperty, QCoreApplication, QObject, Qt, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication, QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
ListDataRole = Qt.UserRole


class Manager(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._model = QStandardItemModel()
        self._model.setItemRoleNames({ListDataRole: b"listdata"})

    @pyqtProperty(QObject, constant=True)
    def model(self):
        return self._model

    def add_list(self, l):
        item = QStandardItem()
        item.setData(l, ListDataRole)
        self._model.appendRow(item)


def main():
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    manager = Manager()

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("manager", manager)

    filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "main.qml")
    url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename)

    def handle_object_created(obj, obj_url):
        if obj is None and url == obj_url:
            QCoreApplication.exit(-1)

    engine.objectCreated.connect(handle_object_created, Qt.QueuedConnection)

    engine.load(url)

    for _ in range(60):
        l = random.sample(range(10, 30), 5)
        manager.add_list(l)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Qt is awesome!!!")

    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Column {
            Repeater {
                model: manager ? manager.model : null

                ComboBox {
                    model: listdata
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. And if in this way I need to pass one list for one ComboBox? Can I somehow do this without a Repeater? Code here - https://pastebin.com/GgLvxacR

Comment: @testtests I don't understand you, and I don't understand the purpose of the link. In SO, specific questions are asked so those of us who try to help you with an answer assume as a basis the information you provide, and according to my point of view my code fulfills what you have required, what is wrong with my answer? Please read [ask] and review the [tour]